# Ensuring the currentState of GlobalKey is Initialized in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `StatelessWidget` as below:

```dart
class StatelessStreamPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>(); // (a)

  StatelessStreamPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Stateless Stream Page'),
      ),
      body: FormBuilder(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FormBuilderTextField(name: 'textField'),
            StreamBuilder<FormBuilderFields>(
              stream: _formKey.currentState?.onChanged, // (b)
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On line (a), I initialize a `GlobalKey` with type `FormBuilderState`. I also need to use a `StreamBuilder`. On line (b), I use `currentState` on `_formKey`, but `currentState` is guaranteed to be `null` on the first render. And `StatelessWidget`s render once.

So, my question is: How can I make sure `currentState` of a `GlobalKey` is initialized (not null) in a `StatelessWidget`, which renders once?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

I use [flutter_form_builder](https://github.com/flutter-form-builder-ecosystem/flutter_form_builder/) and I am currently implementing [this PR](https://github.com/flutter-form-builder-ecosystem/flutter_form_builder/pull/1162).

Flutter Doctor with verbose flag:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Fedora Linux 36 (KDE Plasma) 6.0.17-200.fc36.x86_64, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.3.9 on channel stable at /home/erayerdin/.local/lib/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b8f7f1f986 (7 weeks ago), 2022-11-23 06:43:51 +0900
    • Engine revision 8f2221fbef
    • Dart version 2.18.5
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/erayerdin/.sdks/android/
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/erayerdin/.sdks/android
    • Java binary at: /var/lib/snapd/snap/android-studio/125/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 14.0.5 (Fedora 14.0.5-2.fc36)
    • cmake version 3.25.1
    • ninja version 1.10.2
    • pkg-config version 1.8.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /var/lib/snapd/snap/android-studio/125/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code
    • VS Code at /snap/code/current
    • Flutter extension version 3.56.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Fedora Linux 36 (KDE Plasma) 6.0.17-200.fc36.x86_64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 108.0.5359.124

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: I think you need to change your class to stateful one, because your logic depends on the state of your class.

Comment: So, there's no way to keep this stateless I guess, huh? Is there a way to rebuild the widget once that you know of?

Comment: yes it can't happened in stateless I guess.

Answer (score 0):

For minimal effort, you could wrap your form child with a builder.

This essentially is the same as creating two separate stateless widgets.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  static final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          print(_formKey.currentState);
          return Text(
            'Hello, World!',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```